# Modifying preg_replace_callback to insert ID's in paragraph tags

Tags: php

I was using the following code to insert numerical ID's in paragraph tags...

```
$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace('/(<p( [^>]+)?>)/ie', '"<p\2 id=\"" . $c++ . "\">"', $Article);
$r = preg_replace('/(<p.*?)id="'.($c-1).'"(>)/i', '\1id="Last"\2', $r);
$Article = $r;
```

However, it inserted the id "last" in the last paragraph tag, like this:

```
<p id="1">
<p id="2">
<p id="last">
```

However, it began throwing errors, so I had to change it to preg_replace_callback...

```
$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace_callback('~<p([^>]*)>~i', function($res) use (&$c){
 return '<p'.$res[1].' id="'.$c++.'">';
}, $Article);
```

It works fine except it no longer gives the last paragraph an id = "last"

Does anyone know how to modify it so that the last paragraph has an id="last"? If it isn't too complex, it would be even better if the last paragraph had a numerical ID but a CLASS "last," like this...

```
<p id="1">
<p id="2">
<p id="3" class="last">
```

**EDIT:**

Here's my latest attempt...

```
$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace('/(<p.*?)id="'.($c-1).'"(>)/i', '\1id="Last"\2', $Article);                   
$Article = preg_replace('/(<p.*?id="'.($c-1).'")(>)/i', '\1 class="Last"\2', $Article);
//                        )->

$Content = str_replace('$Name_Common', '<span style="color: #900"><strong>'.$Common.'</strong></span>', $Article);
```

The article displays OK, but the paragraph tags don't have ID's.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You have to "catch" more than before.

```
// replace your line
$r = preg_replace('/(<p.*?)id="'.($c-1).'"(>)/i', '\1id="Last"\2', $r);
// with this one
$r = preg_replace('/(<p.*?id="'.($c-1).'")(>)/i', '\1 class="Last"\2', $r);
//                        )->            )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused. It isn't working for me, probably because I haven't figured out how to make $r = $Article. I've tried the obvious, but it isn't working for me. Also, your code is preg_replace, not preg_replace_callback. That's fine, except preg_replace was causing errors...though your script doesn't produce the same errors. Anyway, I thought I read somewhere that preg_replace has been deprecated and should be replaced with preg_replace_callback. Like I said, I'm confused. ;)

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom , this preg_replace has no `e` modifier. Deprecated preg_replace with `e` modifier only. Read change log from here: http://php.net/preg_replace

Comment: And [there](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) about this modifier

Comment: OK, I see; I never had to switch to _callback in the first place. But I'm still unable to translate $r to my content. I modified my original post, posting my latest code at the end.

Comment: OK, I deleted the first line, but it still isn't working. I'll play with it some more when I get off work tonight. Thx.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62557/discussion-between-sectus-and-david-blomstrom).